# Accessing Form3.pictureBox1 out of Form1

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I search a easy way to access different controls on different forms without any workarounds like I would do this e. g. in Visual Basic 6.

Example:

```
Form3.pictureBox1.Image = MyImage;
```

But somehow C# doesn't allow accessing another controls on another forms not even from my own classes. I already changed the "`pictureBox1`" in Form3 to `public` and still C# doesn't know this control if I type "Form3.".

What I have to do, to access my controls? I already run Visual Studio with elevated privileges (Microsoft answered me on my question in their support area, that elevated privileges are important for accessing the other forms and the controls on it) but nothing helped me sofar. So I stay now with the one form always in C# and this is not suitable to develop any application. Most applications need multiple forms and therefor should be a easy way to access controls from any context in a class or another form. I don't want to use any "set...or get properties" - I do not know even how! Somewhere I found this specific workaround but I usually have so many controls and labels to access in my application, that this would generate a lot of useless overhead, if each control property needs a get- and set-statement or whatever to write to it.

Maybe someone of you knows a more elegant method to do this in a more simple way even if elevation needed.

Comment: Probably, showing your code will be helpful.

Comment: Please show at least a modicum of research. This question doesn't give clear indication of what the goal is, how it is failing, or what you've tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VB6 you could access the default instance of your form by using the Class name, in VB.Net they have continued that behavior. C# doesn't have that behavior, therefore  you have to create your own instance of your Form. Otherwise you are trying to use it like a static Class. Even though you do not want to, the best way to do want you want is to expose them through properties it keeps everything encapsulated.

```
Form3 frm3 = new Form3();
frm3.pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("ImageName");
frm3.Show();
```

Comment: @feedwall that should work with the default references in a C# project. What reference is it complaining about.

Comment: @feedwall make sure you set the picturbox's Modifier property to Public in its propertys

Comment: @feedwall how are you trying to set your Image, what is the code?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13232/discussion-between-mark-hall-and-feedwall)

Answer (score 1):

I think I know what is wrong. `Form1` and `Form3` are in fact classes, so typing `Form1.something` means that `something` must be a static member. In order to be able to access the picture, you need an instance of the class.

To explain this better, here is an example:

```
string a;
```

`string` is the class type, and `a` is an instance of that class.

A method to do this would be to modify the startup code (in windows forms that would be in the `Program.cs` source file), and save the form in a static class, and access it from there.

This is what Program.cs probably looks like:

```
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new Form1());
}
```

You can see that a new instance of Form1 is being created, that is what the new keyword does. You could also do the following:

```
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

    Form1 f = new Form1();
    Application.Run(f);
}
```

The variable `f` contains the form being displayed.

I don't really know how your program works, but anyway... to be able to access members of `Form3`, you need to find the instance. Maybe you have `new Form3().Show()` somewhere in your code, I don't know exactly... but you need to save that to a variable, and that's how you can access it.

Comment: I edited the answer, hopefully that will make things clearer. Technically, a control is a class type, and you can create instances of them. That's how you can have multiple controls of the same type displayed at the same time.

Comment: Instead of doing Form3.Show, create a variable: `Form3 form = new Form3(); form.Show();` Now you can access `form.pictureBox`.

Comment: Maybe the form isn't initialized, and that's why it gives the exception. You could try writing a handler for form.Loaded. In the designer, you actually create the class type. This is how you can display multiple identical forms on the screen at the same time.

Comment: Did you make pictureBox1 public?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the modifier property of the objects to public, than you make a instance of the form and call the object you want

```
Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
frm2.show();
frm2.pictureBox1.Image = "MyImage";
```

Comment: try to change "Form2" to "Form3", Form2 is the name of the Form that you want to call.

Answer (score 0):

Form3 may refer to the class. You need to use an object to access picturebox1 (or make the field static)

Comment: Form3 myForm=new Form3(); Console.WriteLine(myForm.picturebox1.something);

Comment: Well actually myForm is not the same instance that you are interested in so you could make the field static or pass a Form3 reference to the other form or use a singleton Form3 class